# Define constants from mysql database in PHP Codeigniter config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to defining constants from mysql database, but could not load  the database in codeigniter config file.

```
$db =$CI->load->database();
$query = $db->get('constants');
foreach( $query->result() as $row ){ define($row->title, $row->value); }
```

But it is throwing me an error "Undefined variable: CI"

Comment: I don't think so that we can do DB operation in config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the config/config.php, paste the following code.

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();

$query = $db->get('constants');

$result = $query->result();

foreach( $result as $row)
{
    $config[$row->title] = $row->value;
}
```

On Controller Test

```
echo $this->config->item('something');
```

Comment: I upvoted for a creative answer, but this is obviously a bandage for what I suspect is a broken app architecture. You have to be honest, this has Kludge written all over it. Even though CodeIgniter provides all kinds of ways to do things right, there's this ...

Answer (score 0):

To use the CI super object in a config file, you must use:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

Comment: Not working, throwing an error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\CodeIgniter\system\core\CodeIgniter.php

Comment: This is the only way to obtain the CI super object in a config file or library. Are you loading the config file with `$this->config->load()` ??